# Set environemnt variables on Dockerfile, flask server not working

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, dockerfile

I need to set the environment in my Dockerfile (I can't use docker-compose because I will need this dockerfile for kubernetes).
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.1.0-py3

RUN apt -qq -y update \
    && apt -qq -y upgrade

WORKDIR /socialworks-api
COPY . /socialworks-api

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt -y install git

#for mysql
RUN apt install -y libmysqlclient-dev

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["/bin/bash", "./start.sh"]
```

Here is my start.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export $(grep -v '^#' env/docker.env | xargs)
source env/docker.env
python app.py
```

Here is where I start my flask server in app.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("test")
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

The issue is that after these commands, I try to run my docker container and the flask server is being launched (it even prints test in the terminal) and when I try to run http://0.0.0.0:5000/ I am having unable to connect issue on the browser.
Maybe the issue is with CMD in my dockerfile or start.sh file? I am new to Docker. Any help will be appreciated. Locally everything works fine.
Here is the command I use to run the docker container:

```
docker run -it flaskapp
```

Here is the docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
337f1bdacb3e        flaskapp            "/bin/bash ./start.sh"   44 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds       5000/tcp            dazzling_mcclintock
```

Here are the logs:

```
docker logs 337f1bdacb3e
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
2020-04-20 10:02:44.287504: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-04-20 10:02:44.309581: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2394225000 Hz
2020-04-20 10:02:44.310031: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x4971910 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-20 10:02:44.310068: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
test
(10) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Logs are the same what I get when running it locally and locally everything works. Could it be that the flask application is being stopped somehow when running it?

Comment: Please share docker container logs. `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME`

Comment: can you also add the docker command you are running to bring up the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble seems to be that you have not mapped the exposed port of your docker container to your local machine. To remedy this you need to change your run to command to

`docker run -it -p 5000:5000 flaskapp`.

This tells docker to map port 5000 in the running container (the first 5000) to port 5000 on your local machine (the second 5000) [If you wanted to run on it on your local machine port 8080 for instance, instead the flag would be `-p 5000:8080`].

When you do so, the ports section output from `docker ps` should look something like:

`0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Is there a way to map the ports in the dockerfile itself? I already wrote EXPOSE 5000, but as I can see, it was not enough.

Comment: No, you can only specify which ports are available to be mapped. This is what `EXPOSE` does - specify which ports of the container are _available_ to the host machine, but not explicitly any mapping. This needs to be specified when you run the container - if this was done automatically then just doing `docker run` could use many ports of your host (if the container uses many ports), and potentially conflict with other running services. Some useful information around this in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking)